# How should I order a subset of a query returned and place it on the top of the result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query for example:

```
select name from tableA;
```

which gives the following:

```
a
b
c
d1
d2 
d3
e1
e3
```

I would like to have it ordered with the "d's" on top of the list.

e.g.

```
d1
d2
d3
a
b
c
e1
e2
e3
```

I tried to do a union with two queries but it seems to not be working. I believe I'm missing something but can't figure it out.

I got this far:

```
select name from tableA where name like 'd%';
union
select name from tableA;
```

Comment: An addition to perfect answer given: Union doesn't guarante any order. If you like you need to have an 'order by'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using a `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY` clause:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3220/0)

```
SELECT name
FROM TableA
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN name LIKE 'd%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    name
```